# Convert shapefile to SVG while keeping attributes

Tags: shapefile, convert, svg

Is there a way to export shapefile to SVG while keeping attributes?

I tried the mapshaper and QGIS' Mapprinter plugin but with no result, I get the geometry only but I need attributes.

I want when I export to fill the svg id with values from a column so I can join them afterward

Comment: SVG doesn't support attributes, so it seems unlikely.

Comment: I mean I want when I export to fill the svg id with values from a column so I can join them afterward

Comment: What tools/software do you have?

Comment: it will be preferable if I can use qgis or arcgis, but I can try any tool

Comment: Thera was an answer ( can't retrieve it..) to create dynamic svg where the text part came from an attribute, you may try look it up

Comment: Find it ! this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379437/use-text-diagram-for-labeling-in-qgis/379578?r=SearchResults#379578 will let you create svg with text from attributes

Answer (score 1):

You may use mapshaper, using command  line

```bash
# Get data for demo
https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip
# Uncompress
unzip ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip

# From mapshaper, add id to svg output
mapshaper ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp -o format=svg id-field="ADM0_A3" out.svg
For more, see https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/issues/132#issuecomment-223140958 for more
```

Answer (score 0):

To get attribute in your svg just label your feature with that field and export that. It will label the feature in svg too.