# Add a table with attributes based on value for some features

Tags: qgis, labeling, fields-attributes

I have a set of points with contamination data for each one, and I would like to show a table, for each point, for the contaminations that surpass certain threshold, something like this:

[image]

Now, ideally I would like the table to show the Name of each contamination (this is the field name) as well as the value, only if this value exceeds a limit

I have been trying different approaches with labels but without success yet

[image]

Comment: Please provide some exemplary label settings which you tried and note for each, what didn't suit your needs or didn't work.

Comment: Hello, I tried using a rule based label, but using Concatenate expression I was only able to show values in the contamination fields, but I dont know how to show the actual name of the contamination for each one.
Also, I am not sure how to set the rule for the point to show the contaminations, as I need it to be for example: If "Cadmium<5" and "Zincz15"; then I would want the label to appear, but I dont know how to properly write that, I can only set one of the thresholds in the filter rule

Comment: Can you provide exemplary data?

Comment: Can I share an excel table here? I dont see the option :(

Comment: You want to show these labels on a print layout or on the QGIS map canvas?

Comment: Ideally on the Qgis canvas, if it is possible, but more importantly on a print, for the clients final product

Comment: If you were able to create the table outline as an SVG and set parameters for text placement within the SVG definition (see this segment in the docs - https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#svg-symbol) you could achieve something similar. Like in this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379437/use-text-diagram-for-labeling-in-qgis/379578#379578